# Running seq2seq model error

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run the code in this [tutorial](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.md).

When I try to run this command:

```
sudo bazel run -c opt tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py -- --   data_dir ../data/translate/
```

I get the following error:

```
...................
ERROR: Cannot run target //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate.py: Not   executable.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.537s
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target.
```

Any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a lot of mistakes in the Tensorflow tutorial..
I was able to run it by removing the .py, and adding an extra -- before the options like:

bazel run -c opt tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate -- --data_dir /home/minsoo/tensorflowrnn/data

the directory part should be changed according to your system.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it by going to the directory and running:

```
python translate.py
```